# OpenGL fails at intesection of textures

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I've loaded a texture, and displayed it on a cube and on a plane. At the point where the plane and the cube intersect, there are some ugly visual artifacts.

Here are two pictures demonstrating the issue:

Image 1 - what is this:

[image: Image1 - what is this?]

Image 2 - same scenario, other perspective:

[image: Image2 - how to fix?]

Here is how I loaded the image:

```
static const GLenum gl_format[4] = { GL_LUMINANCE, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_BGR, GL_BGRA };

GLuint LoadTGATexture(const char* filename)
{
    //image is already loaded in --- unsigned char[] data - int width - int height - int components
    unsigned int handle;

    glGetFloatv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &max_anisotropy);

    glGenTextures(1, &handle);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, handle);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, components, width, height, 0, gl_format[components - 1], GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, components, width, height, gl_format[components - 1], GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, max_anisotropy);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    delete [] data;
    return handle;
}
```

But how can I fix it, and what is my mistake?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you by any chance have a perspective matrix with a **huge** difference between the near and far clipping plane?

Comment: yes, i had 0.00001 and 10000.0 -> too huge - but if the plane exactly overlaps with another, there are still some stripes (at near 0.01 and far 100.0)

Comment: 'far' really isn't much of a problem, the real issue is 'near' - if you set the near-plane to 0.01, then ~50% of your z-buffer range is between 0.01 and 0.02, even if your far-plane is pretty close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it has nothing to do with your texture.

By the looks of it you have a problem with clipping. I would verify `glEnable(GL_DEPTHTEST)`, make sure that your near-plane when setting the perspective matrix is `>0.0`, meaning not 0.0 and not a negative number. Also make sure that your far-plane isn't some insanely huge number.  I normally stop at 1000.0 with good results. You might want to do something smaller.

Comment: thank you! it's really better now! but if the plane exactly overlaps with another, there are still some stripes... any suggestion?

Comment: @Schnizel1337 If the plane exactly overlaps, there is not really anything you can do. You'll bump into an issue called "z fighting". Google it. You generally want to avoid exact overlaps of geometry.

Comment: This is not called clipping but depth fighting. Also the far plane distance is much less crucial for this that the near plane distance. The depth buffer resolution goes with 1/x, so the closer you move the near plane to the origin, the more depth resolution you loose in the far. Toward the far clipping plane the precision is nearing a linear progression, hence the precision drop due to larger far distances is not so critical. Hence you should choose the near clip plane distance as large as possible, not just >0.

Comment: @Schnizel1337: Unfortunatly, as Bart said, that is a part of 3D graphics. The only fix is to not allow that situation to happen. Even applications like Maya, Blender3D, and Halo have that issue.

Comment: and what would be about `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);` it may be not the best solution, but with nearClip not too small, it should work, right? then the later drawn element "wins" the z-fight

Comment: Yes that would work. And looking at the doc, the way you described it. You would get an entire polygon shown through instead of stripes at least.